# success or error message input javascript bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to change my input in order to display a succes or error icon at the input? like : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation 

Much appreciated. 

and here's my code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[name=subdomain]').keyup(subdomain_check);
    });

    function subdomain_check() {
        var subdomain = $('input[name=subdomain]').val();
        if (subdomain == "") {
            $('input[name=subdomain]');
        } else {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: 'subdomain=' + subdomain,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == 1) {
                        $('input[name=subdomain]').html("The URL already exist!");
                    } else {
                        $('input[name=subdomain]').html("The URL is Valid!");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

The HTML code :

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="install-element-6">
            <span class="required">* </span>subdomain</label>
    <div class="col-md-6"> //<----- I want it here
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-md col-md-6" name="subdomain" placeholder required id="install-element-6"/> // the method.addClass add it here
    </div>
    </div>
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You've only provided javascript. The type of thing you're asking for requires CSS and some way to display the icon. What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Well, i tried this: `if(response == 1){
  $('input[name=subdomain]').css('border', '1px #C33 solid').html("The URL already exist!"); 
  }else{
  $('input[name=subdomain]').css('border', '1px #090 solid').html("The URL is Valid!");
    }` But it doesn't show the glow like in the bootstrap 3

Comment: And it's doesn't display the .html() message. Why not ?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation  why don't you use the predefined bootstrap classes? 
$(jquery object).addClass('has-warning')

Comment: I edited my post because the .addClass() method add it at the input instead i want to add at the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked now and all by adding the method `parent()` to get the element `div` instead of `input`

```
if(response == 1){
            $('input[name=subdomain]').parent().removeClass("has-success");
            $('input[name=subdomain]').parent().addClass("has-error");
        }else{
            $('input[name=subdomain]').parent().removeClass("has-error");
            $('input[name=subdomain]').parent().addClass("has-success");

             }
```